# WebStorm, setting JavaScript Debug with another task running before

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, chrome-debugging

In **WebStorm** I can very easy setup **JavaScript Debug** and then when I run this configuration, IDE opens the Chrome browser and all breakpoints are active. The problem begins when I need to run specific tasks prior to starting debugging, for example running `npm` build script. When I define it in **Before launch** (see the picture below), the Chrome browser not being opened when I activate this debug configuration but being opened after I stop it.

This requires from me, manually run a project from command line and then run **Browser Debug**

Can I define the additional tasks in a way that Chrome will be opened as usually?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process added to **Before launch** section has to return an exit code, the main process is waiting for it to start and thus doesn't start until the first process terminates. This is the way **Before launch** is designed - it's supposed to be used to run some sort of pre-processing before running the main process. You can add a build task (a script that builds your app and then exits) to this section; but `start:dev` likely doesn't exit, it starts the server your application is hosted on, and it has to be running to make your application work, doesn't it? Please remove your npm script from **Before launch**, start it separately or use the **Compound** configuration to start both **npm** script and **Javascript Debug** run configuration concurrently

Comment: Spasibo Lena :)